# Why does the following code for bubble sort give segmentation fault?

Tags: c, c-strings

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char *a[]={"this","is","a","string"};
    char temp[100];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){                               
        for(int j=0;j<3-i;j++){
            if(strcmp(a[j],a[j+1])>0){
                strcpy(temp,a[j]);
                strcpy(a[j],a[j+1]);
                strcpy(a[j+1],temp);
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

The following code is for bubble sorting the strings.It gives segmentation fault.What is wrong in it?

Answer (score 3):

String literals are read-only in C. Your `strcpy(a[j],a[j+1])` and `strcpy(a[j+1], temp)` calls are illegal.

Comment: Thanks a lot.But the code [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-strings-using-bubble-sort-2/) does the same thing and runs well

Comment: Note that that algorithm operates on `char arr[][MAX]` and not on `char*[MAX]`

Comment: @Vedant That code sorts array of character *arrays*. You are sorting array of *pointers*.

Comment: okay thanks @DavideSpataro

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use `strcpy`. The only thing that you have to do is to **swap `a[j]` and `a[j+1]` pointers**.

Make sure that the `for` loop have the correct bounds. The array has size `4`, and valid elements are in the range `[0..4)`

Take a look at the following:

```
int main(){
        char const *a[]={"this","is","a","string"}; //const added
        char *temp = 0; // a simple pointer
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){     //bounds changed                          
                for(int j=0;j<4-1;j++){
                        if(strcmp(a[j],a[j+1])>0){ // swap pointers
                            temp = a[j];
                            a[j] = a[j+1];
                            a[j+1]=temp;
                        }
                }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                printf("%s\n",a[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why is using strcpy() not allowed?

Comment: Take a look at the following. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha . Please be aware that avoiding `strcpy` altogether translates to a much more efficient function.

Comment: Im sorry, that was meant to be 3-i and not 3-1.